# How to Make an Image Fill the Container Height and Retail Aspect Ratio with Bootstrap 4

Tags: css

How can an image fill the parent container height, and retain the aspect ratio?
I have used a similar pattern before (see below), but I believe that Bootstrap 4 may be interfering here. When viewing the image in a mobile view port, the image is stretching vertically.

```css
div#parent { position: relative; }
h1 { color: #FFF }
img#child { 
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: -100;
 }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <img id="child" 
    src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/07/08/08/59/background-1503863_1280.png" alt="Background" />
    <h1>Very very very very very very very very very very very long heading 
    to go over image in mobile view. The image should not stretch 
    vertically.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-size: contain;` to your CSS

```
     img#child {
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        z-index: -100;
        background-size: contain;
     }
```

Output:

[image]

For more info: https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_background-size.asp